# Two graphs with similar relationship between x and y

Tags: geometry

My attempt:

In graph A , $ x \propto \cfrac{1}{y}$  so when $x \to \infty $ then $y \to 0$ and vice versa. So option $2, 3$ are not possible. Option 1 , 4 are possible but this question is single correct so only one option is correct.

---

In graph B a line parallel to $x$-axis is given. If $xy =l$ (from option $4$) where $y=l =$ constant then $y=\frac{l}{x} \Rightarrow  y \propto x$ and vice versa. So option $4$ is correct and if we take $l=1$ then option $1$ is also correct. But answer of question is single correct. So please help me

[image]

Comment: The first one cannot be correct because the ordinate is constant. If the ordinate is $\frac{1}{x}$ and it's constant, then $x$ would be constant. This is not the case according to the abscissa. But you are right in saying that 4 is the correct answer ($xy$). This is also easily seen, as the first graph indicates that $xy=\text{constant}$. Once you choose 4 as the answer, this information is only repeated in the second graph.

Comment: Thank you very much sir.

Answer (score 1):

The answer would be $(4)$, as one can see in the graph A, $y$ and $x$ are related by: $$y = \cfrac{1}{x}$$ and as stated in the question both graph represent same relationship, and it can be seen that Graph B represent contact graph i.e. not depends on $x$ ,then by little algreba $ y = \frac{1}{x}$ can be written as $xy = 1$ , where the R.H.S is always constant, that's what was wanted.

Comment: Why you saying that graph B is not depends on x ? In the graph B, x is variable and y is constant.

Comment: Whatever the value of x, y remains the same. Hence independent.

Comment: OK , I understand your approach. Thanks